# prove of topology and metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove or disprove $f: A \to B$ a function from $A$ to $B$. $A_i$ subset of $A$ and $B_i$ subset of $B$.

1. If $A_0 \subset A_1$ then $f(A_0) \subset f(A_1)$
2. $f(A_0 \cup A_1) = f(A_0) \cup f(A_1)$
3. $f(A_0 \cap A_1) = f(A_0) \cap f(A_1) $

Comment: What do the "IF" mean after b and c . Just that you want to know if this is true, or is there a "then" missing?

Comment: I see you ask questions with quite high frequency. You should learn to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also consider adding your own ideas and solution attempts in your questions. Then they will get better response. The only way to learn math, is by doing the exercises yourself (they are the most important part of learning math).

Comment: OK @sanjab i will include them from my next question. I am new to this will learn it quickly. Thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Note that $f(A_0) = \{f(a) \in B\; |\; a \in A_0 \subset A_1\}$. 
   Then clearly $f(A_0) \subset f(A_1) = \{f(a) \in B\; |\; a \in A_1\}$.
2. $f(A_0 \cup A_1) = \{f(a) \in B\; |\; a \in A_0 \text{ or } a \in A_1\} = f(A_0) \cup f(A_1)$

Answer (score 1):

1) if $y\in f(A_0)$ then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in A_0\subset A_1$, an thus $y\in f(A_1)$.

2) Let $y\in f(A_0\cup A_1)$, then $y=f(x)$ for a $x\in A_0\cup A_1$ and thus $y=f(x)$ for a $x\in A_0$ or for a $x\in A_1$. The reciprocally is the same.

3) Let $y\in f(A_0\cap A_1)$, then $y=f(x)$ for a $x\in A_0\cap A_1$ and thus $y=f(x)$ for a $x\in A_0$ and for $x\in A_1$. The reciprocally is wrong if $f$ is not one to one.